# How to record markup(drawing) and audio narration of ppt/pdf slides

Tags: mouseevent, ms-office, powerpoint, video-capture

Background:

I am currently developing a distant education system for a third world country. Because of limited bandwidth, students can not, or can't afford to, watch video streams from internet.

Requirement:

1. continuous recording of voice.
   teachers hate to record narration for each slides.
2. voice-markup synchronization
   i.e. markup should appear one by one at exact time that they are recorded.

Obviously embedded Ms PowerPoint is not enough.

Question:

Are there some sort of PowerPoint plug-in can achieve that?

How to record mark-ups?

Simply record mouse movement/event and replay those event might work buy it is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [PresentationTube](http://presentationtube.com/). PresentationTube offers a free desktop presentation recorder and YouTube-based video sharing network to help teachers and students produce and share quality video presentations for e-learning in a new way. The recorder allows the presenter to synchronize a variety of visual aids, including presenter's audio and video footage, PowerPoint slides, hand-written text, drawings, and web pages. The platform integrates scrollable slide thumbnails allowing the audience to move to the respective video content and control both the time and progress of video presentation.